# Onde os dados ficam armazenados no MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Faz dois dias que comecei a estudar sobre o [MySQL](https://mysql.com/) e até agora eu só sei o básico dele, sem falar que ele é o primeiro [SBGD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados) que estudo.

Uma coisa muito interessante do MySQL que eu achei, é que ao criar um *database*, ele não me pede um diretório para salvar os dados assim como no [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). Ele simplesmente recebe as instruções que eu passo e deixa os dados em algum lugar de forma que possa ser sempre acessado ao estabelecer uma conexão. E isso me deixou curioso para saber qual é a estrutura das pastas e arquivos de um *database* no MySQL.

Então a minha pergunta é: Onde e de que forma esses dados são armazenados ?

Comment: Porque vocês estão negativando minha pergunta ? Poderiam me ajudar a melhorar a pergunta por favor deixando aqui nos comentários ?

Comment: Eu também não entendo essas negativações em questões que, aparentemente, não têm nada de errado. Ocorreu comigo também em uma pergunta também de SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todas as bases MySQL são armazenadas em diretórios dentro de um diretório DATADIR, que é especificado na configuração. Então, um banco chamado: "BancoApp" ficaria armazenado no $DATADIR/BancoApp.

Existem algumas formas de você descobrir este local:

- Se você tiver acesso ao MySQL, basta executar a query:

  mysql> select @@datadir;

O resultado dessa query será o caminho do banco.

- Se você não tiver acesso ao MySQL, mas tiver acesso ao servidor que
  ele está rodando existem duas opções:

> Linux:

Você pode checar o caminho pro datadir nos argumentos do processo utilizando o comando:

```
$ ps -aux | grep mysql
```

> No Windows, a partir do Vista, o padrão da pasta é:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server %VERSION%\
```